# I can only connect to my GitLab server from a remote network

Tags: git, port, local, server, gitlab

Yesterday at work, I had been happily using my brand new GitLab server (which was back at my house) all day. Pushing, pulling, and merging all worked just fine. When I got home, I wanted to touch up a personal project, but when I tried to pull the repo from my server, I got this message:

`fatal: unable to access 'http://git.ghostlyco.de/revxx14/new-site.git/': Failed connect to git.ghostlyco.de:80; No error`

I thought "Hmm, that's odd. I've been connecting just fine all day." So I tried it a few more times, and got the same error. I tried using the IP address instead of the domain, same deal. Local IP address, exactly the same thing. I tried it on another account on the computer, and got the same error. I tried it on a completely different computer, and got the same error. I tried switching from wired internet to wireless, same deal. I tried rebooting my machine, and yep, same issue. I tried rebooting the server, to no avail.

I went to bed frustrated, I had no idea what could be happening. I can pull up the site just fine in my browser, which added to the confusion.

When I woke up this morning, I had one last idea I could try: a completely different connection. I figured that's the only other difference I had when connecting from work. So I set up internet tethering on my phone, pulled the repo, and...SUCCESS!

So apparently I can't connect to my GitLab server if I'm on the same network. This is blowing my mind. I definitely understand why I wouldn't be able to connect  remotely if I didn't set up port forwarding properly, but within the local network? This makes no sense.

I'm not a networking or command line guy, so I have no idea where to start to look in to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FYI I'm running GitLab on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x86 server, if that makes a difference.

---

EDIT: Apparently the local IP is now working. I guess that's fine? This is so weird. No idea why it can't connect to the IP address/domain.

Comment: Depending upon what is doing your NAT/Address translation (you mention local IP), you probably will not be able to access it by name from  behind that NAT, since a good percentage of those devices cannot hairpin traffic (meaning go in and out on the same interface).  If you need to have the same names both internally and locally you can look at running your own dns server  where your internal servers resolve to internal/local ips when you are home

Comment: Ah, so if I'm understanding you right, it's not connecting because it  can't exit the network to reference itself and re-enter the network. Local IP should be fine then, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Doon for helping me understand what's happening. It sounds like my router can't exit the network, reference itself, and re-enter the network. I may be misunderstanding that, but hey, it gave me an idea.

To fix this, I simply modified the HOSTS file in Windows so that the domain name for the site simply references the local IP.

It was this simple:

`192.168.1.155 git.ghostlyco.de`

I then tried to pull a repo, and it worked! Perfect simple solution. I just have to remember this in case I set up any new machines.

Comment: Yep that is it.  Works fine for workstations but can be annoying for laptops to modify the hosts file.

Comment: Yea, luckily I don't use my laptop for this kind stuff much. Thanks for the help!